# Is there any "Remote Exception" known from RMI in Corba?

Tags: exception, corba

I want to write a forum-like application in Corba and C++ and I wonder is there anything like Remote Exception known from RMI in CORBA? Does CORBA have its own Remote Exception? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

All UserExcptions are essentially remote exceptions, since they can only be raised by the server side.